# How to store each occurrence of multiline string in array using bash regex

Tags: regex, bash

Given a text file `test.txt` with contents:

```
hello
someline1
someline2
...
world1

line that shouldn't match

hello
someline1
someline2
...
world2
```

How can I store both of these multiline matches in separate array indexes?

I'm currently trying to use `regex="hello.*world[12]"`

Unfortunately I can only use native Bash, so Perl etc is off the table. Thanks

Comment: Do you need to do it with pure bash? If you have bash then standard tools like `grep` `sed` `awk` are surely available

Comment: I'm able to use grep, sed and awk - just not any other programming language like Perl or Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `awk` and `mapfile` (bash version >= 4.3)

```sh
#!/bin/bash

mapfile -d '' arr < <(
    awk '/hello/{f=1} f; /world[12]/ && f {f=0; printf "\000"}' test.txt
)
```

```sh
arr=([0]=$'hello\nsomeline1\nsomeline2\n...\nworld1\n' [1]=$'hello\nsomeline1\nsomeline2\n...\nworld2\n')
```

**notes:**

- `awk '/hello/{f=1} f; /world[12]/ && f{f=0; printf "\000"}'`
  . when encountering `hello`, set the flag to true
  . for each line, print it if the flag is true
  . when encountering `world[12]` and the flag is true, set the flag to false and print a `null-byte` delimiter
- `mapfile -d '' arr`
  split the input into an array in which each element was delimited by a `null-byte` (instead of `\n`)

---

version for older bash:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
arr=()
while IFS='' read -r -d '' block
do
    arr+=( "$block" )
done < <(
    awk '/hello/{f=1} f; /world[12]/ && f{f=0; printf "\000"}' test.txt
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work perfectly. Can you please explain how the awk statement works?

Comment: @sharkbites I updated the answer with some explanations, and also corrected a potential bug

Comment: If I wanted to put a singular parenthesis `)` instead of `world[12]`, do you know how I can do this? I can't seem to escape it...maybe because its in singular quotes? But I can't seem to change it to double quotes either.

Comment: `\(` doesn't work?

Comment: doesn't seem to :(

Comment: tested with `/world\)/` and it works, you may have another problem?

Comment: Hi @Fravadona, I'm trying to do a similar thing now but with Unix, except it doesn't seem to like your `awk` command. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @sharkbites this awk command is POSIX compliant and should be able to run on every UNIX; if you’re running Solaris then try with /usr/xpg4/bin/awk

Comment: @Fravodona, yep that seemed to fix my awk issue. But the assignment of "block" doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 2):

As the regex of `bash` does not have such functionality as `findall()` function of `python`, we need to capture the matched substring one by one in the loop.

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

str=$(<test.txt)
regex="hello.world[12]"

while [[ $str =~ ($regex)(.*) ]]; do
    ary+=( "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" )       # store the match into an array
    str="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"            # remaining substring
done

for i in "${!ary[@]}"; do               # see the result
    echo "[$i] ${ary[$i]}"
done
```

Output:

```
[0] hello
world1
[1] hello
world2
```

**[Edit]**
If there exist some lines between "hello" and "world", we need to change the approach as the regex of bash does not support the shortest match. Then how about:

```
regex1="hello"
regex2="world"

while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ $regex1 ]]; then
        str="$line"$'\n'
        f=1
    elif (( f )); then
        str+="$line"$'\n'
        if [[ $line =~ $regex2 ]]; then
            ary+=("$str")
            f=0
        fi
    fi
done < test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely close to what I'm after, but I also need it to match on X number of lines between "hello" and "world". I'll edit the question to better reflect that

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've updated my answer accordingly. I'm afraid this may not be a smart solution. Sigh...